# Understanding delegates in iOS programming

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am new to iOS programming and I'm trying to understand and begin implementing delegates to get information between view controllers and any other use they may have.

I've used [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589240/trying-to-understand-protocol-delegates-in-swift/25589327#25589327?s=1167091c8e2a40d2bcf2ba92f1931845) to get a little further, but I can't comment as i just created this account, so i can't ask a question on the post. I copied drewag's example but this line 
`@IBOutlet weak var delegate: ViewControllerBDelegate?`
 is giving me an error "IBOutlet property cannot have non-object type SecondViewControllerDelegate"

I deleted it and it runs but the information is not being sent between the two view controllers. I thought i was beginning to understand delegates but just getting them implemented is beginning to get frustrating. I've been at this for a few days now.

FirstViewController:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var theMap: MKMapView!

func requiredText() -> String {
    return "test"
}
```

SecondViewcontroller:

```
    protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func requiredText() -> String
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func decide(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
            self.label.text = actualDelegate.requiredText()
    }
}
```

So my question simply is what am I doing wrong? I thought i followed the example correctly.

Comment: rob's suggestion fixed my error. however my code still isn't doing what I'd like it to do. It should be changing the label text to the sent String which in this case is "test" when i click the button which is attached to my decide function.

Comment: If i pull out `self.label.text = actualDelegate.requiredText()` (and the declaration) from the loop Xcode says "SecondViewControllerDelegate does not have a member function called requiredText"

EDIT: i added ! and it took away the error, but i got BAD_INSTRUCTION

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `SecondViewControllerDelegate` like this:

```
@objc protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func requiredText() -> String
}
```

This is just a quirk of the Swift compiler or the runtime.  The `@objc` directive makes the compiler emit additional information about the protocol.  At runtime, the program uses that information to verify the delegate implements the protocol's methods.  Since these objects are loaded from a xib (or storyboard), the compiler can't verify it at compile time.

Comment: Well I would upvote, but I can't. But thank you! It got my error to disappear. Now when i run it, and press the button which triggers my "decide" function it doesn't change the text. Should my @IBOutlet delegate be linked to something? It is just an open circle next to it. I can't drag the view controller to connect to it.

Thanks again!

Comment: From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) "Optional protocol requirements can only be specified if your protocol is marked with the @objc attribute." What makes this an optional protocol?

Answer (score 1):

You do not set your actualDelegate = firstViewController,so actualDelegate is always nil.
If you use storyboard,set Identifier of firstViewController as "first"
then

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
        var firstview = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as FirstViewController?;
        self.delegate = firstview;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Comment: thank you! Now I just don't really understand what 
`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as FirstViewController?;` does. is it creating a new object of the class FirstViewController? or is it just assigning a local name to the already created object (from the storyboard)?

EDIT: I just looked up what instantiate means. I'm guessing its the latter?

Comment: `self.label.text = actualDelegate!.requiredText()` is giving a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION